# Extract rolling maximum value based on column value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data that I've performed cluster analysis on and need to find breakpoints based on population density. The clusters overlap heavily, so I've sorted the data by population density and want to extract the last value before the 'cluster' column switches to another cluster. Basically the data looks like this:

```
cluster  PopDens
1        5
1        7
2        8
2        9
1        10
1        12
3        14
1        16
```

And I would want it to return the following:

```
Cluster  PopDens
1        7
2        9
1        12
3        14
1        16
```

How would I go about achieving this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R it could be done using:

```
x[cumsum(rle(x$cluster)$lengths),]
#  cluster PopDens
#2       1       7
#4       2       9
#6       1      12
#7       3      14
#8       1      16
```

---

This also translates quite directly to `data.table` in case you are interested:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[cumsum(rle(cluster)$lengths)]
```

And of course we can also do it in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
slice(x, cumsum(rle(cluster)$len))
```

Comment: clever use of `rle`!

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` the `rleid()`function can by used for grouping:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, .(PopDens = last(PopDens)), .(rleid(cluster), cluster)][, rleid := NULL][]
#   cluster PopDens
#1:       1       7
#2:       2       9
#3:       1      12
#4:       3      14
#5:       1      16
```

There are alternative ways to achieve the same result:

```
DF[, .(PopDens = PopDens[.N]), .(rleid(cluster), cluster)][, rleid := NULL][]
DF[, .(PopDens = tail(PopDens, 1), .(rleid(cluster), cluster)][, rleid := NULL][]
DF[, .SD[.N], .(rleid(cluster), cluster)][, rleid := NULL][]
DF[, tail(.SD, 1), .(rleid(cluster), cluster)][, rleid := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, tail(.I,1), rleid(cluster)]$V1]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    cluster PopDens
> 1:       1       7
> 2:       2       9
> 3:       1      12
> 4:       3      14
> 5:       1      16
> ```